# Why do language models produce different outputs for same prompt?

Tags: deep-learning, transformer, language-model, natural-language-generation, forward-pass

For conventional 'Neural Networks', the weights simply act as a transformation in highly multi-dimensional space; for a forward pass, the output is always the same since there is no stochastic weighting component in the process.

However, in Transformers (self-attention based encoder-decoder type architecture to be specific) we get different outputs with the same prompts (assuming $T > 0$). This doesn't make sense to me because the set of weights are always static, so the *probability distribution* produced should be the same; this simple decoding should yield the same output.

However, in practice, we observe that it is not actually the case.
Any reasons why?

Answer (score 3):

Language models produce a probability distribution over a set of words. You determine the next word by *sampling* from this distribution. So, determining the next word is stochastic even though the distribution is the same given the initial prompt.

Comment: Worth mentioning the role of T in adjusting the distribution for sampling

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question but, shoudn't there be a seed to set to make the sampling reproducible?